Plot Mesh with the given coordinates ListDensityPlot
Assume I have a set of points {x_i,y_i,f_i}, i=1;;N, which are not equidistant. Now I am plotting them via ListDensityPlot[{{x_1,y_1,f_1},{x_2,y_2,f_2},......}].
How I can plot a Mesh, which with crossections in the defined coordinates {x1,y1},{x2,y2},... etc. ? With using Mesh->All it plots mesh but equidistant, omitting defined points.
UPD
xi = Transpose@RandomInteger[100, 20];
yi = Transpose@RandomInteger[100, 20];
fi = Transpose@RandomInteger[100, 20];
SETi = Transpose@{xi, yi, fi};
{ListDensityPlot[SETi, GridLines -> Automatic], 
 ListDensityPlot[SETi, Mesh -> All]}

As a result I have:,
but I would prefer to have the following, with the grids given by coordinates xi and yi:
P.S. I would expect it relates to MeshFunctions, but I have no idea how to implement it.

Please includes an example of the set of points so we can play with it.

ListDensityPlot[SETi, MeshFunctions -> {#1 & , #2 & },   Mesh -> {xi, yi}]

@cvgmt Thank you very much. Could you write it as an answer so that I can accept it ? It wpuld be great if you could add points to the intersection grid points ?
Thank you !


Set the MeshFunctions to {#1 & , #2 & } and with Mesh->{xi,yi}
I don't know how to automatic add the intersecton grid points, here we Select the intersection point by the function RegionMember@reg.

xi = Transpose@RandomInteger[100, 20];
yi = Transpose@RandomInteger[100, 20];
fi = Transpose@RandomInteger[100, 20];
SETi = Transpose@{xi, yi, fi};

reg=ConvexHullMesh@Transpose@{xi, yi};
ListDensityPlot[SETi, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, Mesh -> {xi, yi},
  Epilog -> {Red, 
   Point@Select[Tuples[{xi, yi}], 
     RegionMember@reg]}]



Add the solution by the questioner.

ListDensityPlot[SETi, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, Mesh -> {xi, yi},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[Transpose@{xi, yi}]}]



Thank you ! I meant picking онли those points given by SETi. Thanks to your detailed answer I was able to get the solution by:
ListDensityPlot[SETi, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, Mesh -> {xi, yi},   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[Transpose@{xi, yi}]}]
